# Smartest way to apply matrix multiplication on a rolling window

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

This is a use-case that I encounter quite often, for example when I want to compute a spectrogram matrix. Given a fixed matrix M (FFT matrix) and a vector v (audio signal), compute the matrix N such that each column i of N is the product M * v.segment(i * window_hop, i * window_hop + window_size).

This can be easily implemented, since the size of N is known, by preallocating then iterating through the columns.

I feel like there is something smarter that can be done, namely constructing a matrix V where each column i of V is v.segment(i * window_hop, i * window_hop + window_size). Then N = M * V, no need for a for loop and everything can be parallelized smoothly (you can cut v into chunks if needed).

The bottom line of this method is the construction of V. Is there a way to construct V that is both fast and memory-efficient? (since V has a lot of repetitions if window_hop < window_size)

Is there an even better way to perform this calculation?

Comment: sounds like a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/, but from a programming perspective, it sounds like you could hack something to make the horizontal-step of a matrix equal to its own vertical-step. It could well play havoc with the existing optimisation code though.

Comment: It looks as if certain partial products can be re-used between windows, because many of the values are the same and they shift by some predictable delta. That is to say, when you are doing overlapping FFT's.

Comment: Well, if we agree on the solution (compressing several matrix / vector multiplications into one matrix / matrix multiplication), what is the most efficient way to create a stacking of segments of v? Using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The [EigenFFT package](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=EigenFFT) provides an API for one-dimensional FFTs using either the kissfft or FFTW library to efficiently process your input.

Going beyond the FFT case, it seems to me that what you're looking for is an efficient way to implement convolutions using Eigen matrices. A [nice solution](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=96407) for the 2D case was posted on the Eigen forum a while back.

Comment: Please note that this question is independent of the type of calculation you want to perform (FFT / other). Thinking about it the convolution solution would be efficient iff window_hop = 1, meaning that the size of one axis of N should have the same length as the audio. This is not the case, and window_hop is about 350. Using a convolution would require to select 1 column every 350 columns, thus making a large part of the calculation inefficient.